# Health insurance options on a US E-2 visa?

Tags: usa, visa, health-insurance

I am applying for an E-2 visa to develop my business in the US.

I am currently the founder, CEO and only employee of my company, and wondering what are my options to be covered by health insurance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have exactly the same options as any other (small) business owner. I suggest asking your local chamber of commerce personnel for the initial leads.